# OpenAI API: How do I count tokens before(!) I send an API request?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api, gpt-3, gpt-4

OpenAI's text models have a context length, e.g.: Curie has a context length of 2049 tokens.
They provide max_tokens and stop parameters to control the length of the generated sequence. Therefore the generation stops either when stop token is obtained, or max_tokens is reached.

The issue is: when generating a text, I don't know how many tokens my prompt contains. Since I do not know that, I cannot set max_tokens = 2049 - number_tokens_in_prompt.

This prevents me from generating text dynamically for a wide range of text in terms of their length. What I need is to continue generating until the stop token.

My questions are:

- How can I count the number of tokens in Python API? So that I will set max_tokens parameter accordingly.
- Is there a way to set max_tokens to the max cap so that I won't need to count the number of prompt tokens?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

As stated in the official [OpenAI article](https://help.openai.com/en/articles/4936856-what-are-tokens-and-how-to-count-them):

> To further explore tokenization, you can use our interactive [Tokenizer](https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer)
> tool, which allows you to calculate the number of tokens and see how
> text is broken into tokens. **Alternatively, if you'd like to tokenize
> text programmatically, use [Tiktoken](https://github.com/openai/tiktoken) as a fast BPE tokenizer
> specifically used for OpenAI models.** Other such libraries you can
> explore as well include [transformers package](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/gpt2#gpt2tokenizerfast) for Python or the
> [gpt-3-encoder package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gpt-3-encoder) for NodeJS.

A tokenizer can split the text string into a list of tokens, as stated in the official [OpenAI example](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/How_to_count_tokens_with_tiktoken.ipynb) on counting tokens with Tiktoken:

> Tiktoken is a fast open-source tokenizer by OpenAI.
>
> Given a text string (e.g., `"tiktoken is great!"`) and an encoding
> (e.g., `"cl100k_base"`), a tokenizer can split the text string into a
> list of tokens (e.g., `["t", "ik", "token", " is", " great", "!"]`).
>
> Splitting text strings into tokens is useful because GPT models see
> text in the form of tokens. Knowing how many tokens are in a text
> string can tell you:
>
> - whether the string is too long for a text model to process and
> - how much an OpenAI API call costs (as usage is priced by token).

Tiktoken supports 3 encodings used by OpenAI models ([source](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/How_to_count_tokens_with_tiktoken.ipynb)):

| Encoding name | OpenAI models |
| --- | --- |
| `cl100k_base` | `gpt-4`, `gpt-3.5-turbo`, `text-embedding-ada-002` |
| `p50k_base` | `text-davinci-003`, `text-davinci-002` |
| `r50k_base` | [GPT-3 models](https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3) |

For `cl100k_base` and `p50k_base` encodings:

- Python: [tiktoken](https://github.com/openai/tiktoken/blob/main/README.md)
- .NET / C#: [SharpToken](https://github.com/dmitry-brazhenko/SharpToken)
- Java: [jtokkit](https://github.com/knuddelsgmbh/jtokkit)

For `r50k_base` encodings, tokenizers are available in many languages:

- Python: [tiktoken](https://github.com/openai/tiktoken/blob/main/README.md) (or alternatively [GPT2TokenizerFast](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/gpt2#transformers.GPT2TokenizerFast))
- JavaScript: [gpt4-tokenizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gpt4-tokenizer), [gpt3-tokenizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gpt3-tokenizer), [gpt-3-encoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gpt-3-encoder)
- .NET / C#: [GPT Tokenizer](https://github.com/dluc/openai-tools)
- Java: [gpt2-tokenizer-java](https://github.com/hyunwoongko/gpt2-tokenizer-java)
- PHP: [GPT-3-Encoder-PHP](https://github.com/CodeRevolutionPlugins/GPT-3-Encoder-PHP)

Note that `gpt-3.5-turbo` and `gpt-4` use tokens in the same way as other models as stated in the official [OpenAI documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/chat/managing-tokens):

> Chat models like `gpt-3.5-turbo` and `gpt-4` use tokens in the same way as
> other models, but because of their message-based formatting, it's more
> difficult to count how many tokens will be used by a conversation.
>
> If a conversation has too many tokens to fit within a model’s maximum
> limit (e.g., more than 4096 tokens for `gpt-3.5-turbo`), you will have
> to truncate, omit, or otherwise shrink your text until it fits. Beware
> that if a message is removed from the messages input, the model will
> lose all knowledge of it.
>
> Note too that very long conversations are more likely to receive
> incomplete replies. For example, a `gpt-3.5-turbo` conversation that is
> 4090 tokens long will have its reply cut off after just 6 tokens.

### How do I use tiktoken?

1. Install or upgrade tiktoken: `pip install --upgrade tiktoken`
2. You have two options.

**OPTION 1: Search in the table above for the correct encoding for a given OpenAI model**

If you run `get_tokens_1.py`, you'll get the following output:

> 9

**get_tokens_1.py**

```
import tiktoken

def num_tokens_from_string(string: str, encoding_name: str) -> int:
    encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding(encoding_name)
    num_tokens = len(encoding.encode(string))
    return num_tokens

print(num_tokens_from_string("Hello world, let's test tiktoken.", "cl100k_base"))
```

**OPTION 2: Use `tiktoken.encoding_for_model()` to automatically load the correct encoding for a given OpenAI model**

If you run `get_tokens_2.py`, you'll get the following output:

> 9

**get_tokens_2.py**

```
import tiktoken

def num_tokens_from_string(string: str, encoding_name: str) -> int:
    encoding = tiktoken.encoding_for_model(encoding_name)
    num_tokens = len(encoding.encode(string))
    return num_tokens

print(num_tokens_from_string("Hello world, let's test tiktoken.", "gpt-3.5-turbo"))
```

*Note: If you take a careful look at the `usage` field in the OpenAI API response, you'll see that it reports `10` tokens used for an identical message. That's `1` token more than Tiktoken. I still haven't figured out why. I tested this in the past (see my [past answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76356218/10347145)). As @Jota mentioned in the comment below, there still seems to be a mismatch between the token usage reported by the OpenAI API response and Tiktoken.*

Comment: Is there Tiktoken for NodeJS?

Comment: @AnshumanKumar Yes: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dqbd/tiktoken

Comment: The tokens calculated with the function indicated by Chat GPT do not match those returned by Chat GPT in the response... it is impossible to calculate the max_tokens var.

Comment: @Jota See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76356218/10347145).

Comment: Why is this ANSWER better than tiktoken's DOCS???

Comment: @RamiAwar It's great to hear that. :) Probably because I combined tiktoken docs, OpenAI docs, and code I personally tested.

Comment: For NodeJS [this gpt4-tokenizer npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gpt4-tokenizer) seems promising:

Comment: anyone has ideas about how to handle functions?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I do it with Python 3.
Then you can pass the model name or the encoding string. You can get the encoding, the tokens or the token count.

**token_helper.py:**

```
import tiktoken

def encoding_getter(encoding_type: str):
    """
    Returns the appropriate encoding based on the given encoding type (either an encoding string or a model name).
    """
    if "k_base" in encoding_type:
        return tiktoken.get_encoding(encoding_type)
    else:
        return tiktoken.encoding_for_model(encoding_type)

def tokenizer(string: str, encoding_type: str) -> list:
    """
    Returns the tokens in a text string using the specified encoding.
    """
    encoding = encoding_getter(encoding_type)
    tokens = encoding.encode(string)
    return tokens

def token_counter(string: str, encoding_type: str) -> int:
    """
    Returns the number of tokens in a text string using the specified encoding.
    """
    num_tokens = len(tokenizer(string, encoding_type))
    return num_tokens
```

Works like this

```
>>> import token_helper
>>> token_helper.token_counter("This string will be counted as tokens", "gpt-3.5-turbo"))
7
```

Answer (score 1):

With the information contained in the comments, I made this: https://gist.github.com/buanzo/7cdd2c34fc0bb25c71b857a16853c6fa

It is a count_tokens implementation that tries tiktoken, nltk and fallbacks to .split()

It includes a simple TokenBuffer implementation as well.

We can import the count_tokens function from the token_counter module and call it with our text string as follows:

```
from token_counter import count_tokens
text = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
result = count_tokens(text, debug=True)
print(result)
```

If all the required libraries are available the result is better but even without tiktoken nor nltk, the function should return a dictionary with the number of tokens and the method used to count them. For example:

{'n_tokens': 9, 'method': 'tiktoken'}

Answer (score 0):

### **COUNTING INPUT TOKENS**

If you want to count the tokens used by a Chat Completion API request, which has other metadata like `role` and `name` in addition to the raw  prompt (`content`), then see the excerpts below from [OpenAI's cookbook](https://cookbook.openai.com/examples/how_to_count_tokens_with_tiktoken#6-counting-tokens-for-chat-completions-api-calls).

**Source Code**

```py
def num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613"):
    """Return the number of tokens used by a list of messages."""
    try:
        encoding = tiktoken.encoding_for_model(model)
    except KeyError:
        print("Warning: model not found. Using cl100k_base encoding.")
        encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding("cl100k_base")
    if model in {
        "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
        "gpt-3.5-turbo-16k-0613",
        "gpt-4-0314",
        "gpt-4-32k-0314",
        "gpt-4-0613",
        "gpt-4-32k-0613",
        }:
        tokens_per_message = 3
        tokens_per_name = 1
    elif model == "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301":
        tokens_per_message = 4  # every message follows <|start|>{role/name}\n{content}<|end|>\n
        tokens_per_name = -1  # if there's a name, the role is omitted
    elif "gpt-3.5-turbo" in model:
        print("Warning: gpt-3.5-turbo may update over time. Returning num tokens assuming gpt-3.5-turbo-0613.")
        return num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-3.5-turbo-0613")
    elif "gpt-4" in model:
        print("Warning: gpt-4 may update over time. Returning num tokens assuming gpt-4-0613.")
        return num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model="gpt-4-0613")
    else:
        raise NotImplementedError(
            f"""num_tokens_from_messages() is not implemented for model {model}. See https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/main/chatml.md for information on how messages are converted to tokens."""
        )
    num_tokens = 0
    for message in messages:
        num_tokens += tokens_per_message
        for key, value in message.items():
            num_tokens += len(encoding.encode(value))
            if key == "name":
                num_tokens += tokens_per_name
    num_tokens += 3  # every reply is primed with <|start|>assistant<|message|>
    return num_tokens
```

**Usage**

```py
# let's verify the function above matches the OpenAI API response

from openai import OpenAI
import os

client = OpenAI(api_key=os.environ.get("OPENAI_API_KEY", "<your OpenAI API key if not set as env var>"))

example_messages = [
    {
        "role": "system",
        "content": "You are a helpful, pattern-following assistant that translates corporate jargon into plain English.",
    },
    {
        "role": "system",
        "name": "example_user",
        "content": "New synergies will help drive top-line growth.",
    },
    {
        "role": "system",
        "name": "example_assistant",
        "content": "Things working well together will increase revenue.",
    },
    {
        "role": "system",
        "name": "example_user",
        "content": "Let's circle back when we have more bandwidth to touch base on opportunities for increased leverage.",
    },
    {
        "role": "system",
        "name": "example_assistant",
        "content": "Let's talk later when we're less busy about how to do better.",
    },
    {
        "role": "user",
        "content": "This late pivot means we don't have time to boil the ocean for the client deliverable.",
    },
]

for model in [
    "gpt-3.5-turbo-0301",
    "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613",
    "gpt-3.5-turbo",
    "gpt-4-0314",
    "gpt-4-0613",
    "gpt-4",
    ]:
    print(model)
    # example token count from the function defined above
    print(f"{num_tokens_from_messages(example_messages, model)} prompt tokens counted by num_tokens_from_messages().")
    # example token count from the OpenAI API
    response = client.chat.completions.create(model=model,
    messages=example_messages,
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=1)
    print(f'{response.usage.prompt_tokens} prompt tokens counted by the OpenAI API.')
    print()
```

**Output**

```py
127 prompt tokens counted by num_tokens_from_messages().
127 prompt tokens counted by the OpenAI API.

gpt-3.5-turbo-0613
129 prompt tokens counted by num_tokens_from_messages().
129 prompt tokens counted by the OpenAI API.

gpt-3.5-turbo
Warning: gpt-3.5-turbo may update over time. Returning num tokens assuming gpt-3.5-turbo-0613.
129 prompt tokens counted by num_tokens_from_messages().
129 prompt tokens counted by the OpenAI API.

gpt-4-0314
129 prompt tokens counted by num_tokens_from_messages().
129 prompt tokens counted by the OpenAI API.

gpt-4-0613
129 prompt tokens counted by num_tokens_from_messages().
129 prompt tokens counted by the OpenAI API.

gpt-4
Warning: gpt-4 may update over time. Returning num tokens assuming gpt-4-0613.
129 prompt tokens counted by num_tokens_from_messages().
129 prompt tokens counted by the OpenAI API.
```

Important note from the Cookbook:

> Note that the exact way that tokens are counted from messages may change from model to model. Consider the counts from the function below an estimate, not a timeless guarantee.

### **SETTING MAX TOKENS**

In the Chat Completion API request, [`max_tokens`](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat-create-max_tokens) represents the maximum tokens for the *generated output*. To simplify the process of setting `max_tokens`, you can make a function:

```py
def max_tokens(messages, model):
    input_tokens = num_tokens_from_messages(messages, model=model)
    context_length = get_context_length(model)
    return context_length - input_tokens

def get_context_length(model):
    if model == "gpt-3.5-turbo-0613":
        return 4096
    # Add additional model context windows here.
    else:
        raise ValueError(f"No context length known for model: {model}")
```

### **REFERENCES**

1. OpenAI Cookbook: https://cookbook.openai.com/examples/how_to_count_tokens_with_tiktoken#6-counting-tokens-for-chat-completions-api-calls
2. OpenAI API Reference: https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create#chat-create-max_tokens
3. Community Forum: https://community.openai.com/t/how-the-max-tokens-are-considered/313514
4. OpenAI Model Documentation for Context Windows: https://platform.openai.com/docs/models/gpt-3-5-turbo