# OpenAI API: How to count tokens before API request

Tags: r, nlp, openai-api

I would like to count the tokens of my OpenAI API request in `R` before sending it `(version gpt-3.5-turbo`). Since the OpenAI API [has rate limits](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/rate-limits/overview), this seems important to me.

Example:

The function I use to send requests:

```
ask_chatgpt <- function(prompt) {
      response <- POST(
        url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", 
        add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", api_key)),
        content_type_json(),
        encode = "json",
        body = list(
          model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
          messages = list(list(
            role = "user", 
            content = prompt
          ))
        )
      )
      str_trim(content(response)$choices[[1]]$message$content)
    }
```

Example

```r
api_key <- "your_openai_api_key" 

library(httr)
library(tidyverse)

#Calls the ChatGPT API with the given prompt and returns the answer
ask_chatgpt <- function(prompt) {
  response <- POST(
    url = "https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", 
    add_headers(Authorization = paste("Bearer", api_key)),
    content_type_json(),
    encode = "json",
    body = list(
      model = "gpt-3.5-turbo",
      messages = list(list(
        role = "user", 
        content = prompt
      ))
    )
  )
  str_trim(content(response)$choices[[1]]$message$content)
}

prompt <- "how do I count the token in R for gpt-3.45-turbo?"

ask_chatgpt(prompt)
#> [1] "As an AI language model, I am not sure what you mean by \"count the token in R for gpt-3.5-turbo.\" Please provide more context or clarification so that I can better understand your question and provide an appropriate answer."
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

I would like to calculate/estimate as how many tokens `prompt` will need with `gtp-3.5-turbo`

There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75804599/openai-api-how-do-i-count-tokens-before-i-send-an-api-request) for gtp-3 and `python`, where the tiktoken library is recommended. However, I could not find a similar library in `R`.

OpenAI [also recommends tiktoken](https://platform.openai.com/tokenizer) or `gpt-3-encoder` package for JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenAI has their own tokenizer so you probably won't be able to reproduce it. Instead, I would just recommend using their python API via the `reticulate` package

First, install the `tiktoken` package via the command line using:

```
pip install tiktoken
```

Then, in R

```
library(reticulate)
tiktoken <- import("tiktoken")
encoding <- tiktoken$encoding_for_model("gpt-3.5-turbo")
prompt <- "how do I count the token in R for gpt-3.45-turbo?"
length(encoding$encode(prompt))
# [1] 19
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I do it, with these helpers you can get the encoding, tokens and token count based on either model name or encoding string.

```
# token_helper.R
library(reticulate)
tiktoken <- import("tiktoken")

encoding_getter <- function(encoding_type) {
  if (grepl("k_base", encoding_type)) {
    tiktoken$get_encoding(encoding_type)
  } else {
    tiktoken$encoding_for_model(encoding_type)
  }
}

tokenizer <- function(string, encoding_type) {
  encoding <- encoding_getter(encoding_type)
  tokens <- encoding$encode(string)
  tokens
}

token_counter <- function(string, encoding_type) {
  tokens <- tokenizer(string, encoding_type)
  num_tokens <- length(tokens)
  num_tokens
}
```

To count tokens, you can call the token_counter function as shown below:

```
library(reticulate)
token_helper <- import("token_helper")
token_helper$token_counter("This string will be counted as tokens", "gpt-3.5-turbo")
```