# OpenAI ChatGPT (GPT-3.5) API: Why does the API report more prompt_tokens used for the messages parameter than I thought it would?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I'm using the `gpt-3.5-turbo` model and sending the following message to the OpenAI API: `What is the most beautiful country?`

I'm sending it as a JSON object: `{"role":"user","content":"What is the most beautiful country?"}`

I thought it would return like `7` tokens for `prompt_tokens`, but it doesn't. It's returning `15` tokens for `prompt_tokens`. Even when sending just `.`, it's returning like `9` tokens for `prompt_tokens`.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you send `{"role": "user", "content": "What is the most beautiful country?"}` as the `messages` parameter, it's not only `What is the most beautiful country?` that is sent to the OpenAI API endpoint, but it seems like the whole `"role": "user", "content": "What is the most beautiful country?"`.

I was able to confirm this using [tiktoken](https://github.com/openai/tiktoken).

If you run `get_tokens_long_example.py` you'll get the following output:

> 14

**get_tokens_long_example.py**

```
import tiktoken

def num_tokens_from_string(string: str, encoding_name: str) -> int:
    """Returns the number of tokens in a text string."""
    encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding(encoding_name)
    num_tokens = len(encoding.encode(string))
    return num_tokens

print(num_tokens_from_string("'role':'user','content':'What is the most beautiful country?'", "cl100k_base"))
```

If you run `get_tokens_short_example.py` you'll get the following output:

> 8

**get_tokens_short_example.py**

```
import tiktoken

def num_tokens_from_string(string: str, encoding_name: str) -> int:
    """Returns the number of tokens in a text string."""
    encoding = tiktoken.get_encoding(encoding_name)
    num_tokens = len(encoding.encode(string))
    return num_tokens

print(num_tokens_from_string("'role':'user','content':'.'", "cl100k_base"))
```

You said that the OpenAI API reports `15` tokens used in the first example and `9` tokens used in the second example. You probably noticed that I got `14` and `8` tokens using tiktoken (i.e., 1 token less in both examples). This seems to be a [known tiktoken problem](https://github.com/openai/tiktoken/issues/71) that should have been [solved](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/pull/254).

Anyway, I didn't dig that deep to figure out why I still get 1 token less, but I was able to prove that it's not only `What is the most beautiful country?` that is sent to the OpenAI API endpoint.

For more information about tiktoken, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75804599/openai-api-how-do-i-count-tokens-before-i-send-an-api-request/75804651#75804651).

Comment: Thank you Rok, yes when using Tokenizer and this prompt: "role":"user","content":"What is the most beautiful country?". It returns 14 tokens and now I believe the extra token was coming from Openai api. I was thinking that extra token was from the curly brackets. Just to make sure, the curly brackets are not counted or are they?

Comment: @RayRojas Hm, I'm not sure about curly brackets, but I would say they aren't counted.